# UIScrollView with AutoLayout and without 'width' constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, width, constraints

I am creating an app, in which, I like to create a UIScrollView that will contain a number of other views that extend beyond the screen size. The size of the content inside UIScrollView is not something I have control over, and is downloaded from the web, and hence I am using UIScrollview.

As described in a number of sites, and as demonstrated in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCWxHLBQ-A , it is possible to set a UIScrollView with AutoLayout enabled (it is important to me to have AutoLayout enabled).

Now, the problem is, there is a 'width' constraint added to the subview as shown in the video link above. For me, I like to have that constraint removed (to be able to support multiple widths).

If I remove the width constraint, there will be a horizontal scroll bar appearing in the view. I would like to set the width to be the screen size, without setting an absolute pixel size as shown in the vid. How can I do that? How can I ensure that a horizontal scroll bar does not appear when I remove the width constraint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your scrollview, `setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator` to `NO`

```
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Comment: This will remove the indicator, however, will keep width bigger than the screen, right?

Comment: Thanks, however, this is not solving the problem, it is hiding it. I do not think it is a proper way to solve the problem at hand unfortunately.